# Analysis differentiability FTC

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Studying for a final, and need help with this question, can someone please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be fixed, and $c \in (a,b)$. Then, we want to show that $F' = f$ on $[a,b]$, and we know that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and there exists a $\delta_c >0$ such that $|f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon$, when $|x -c| < \delta_c$.

So, $\int_c^x f(t)dt \leq (f(c) + \varepsilon)(x-c)$, since that is the upper bound of $f(t)$ on $[c,x]$.

Then we have that 
$$
\left| \frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c} -f(c) \right| = \left| \frac{\int_c^x f(t)dt}{x-c} -f(c)\right| \leq \left| \frac{(f(c)+\varepsilon)(x-c)}{(x-c)} -f(c) \right| = f(c) + \varepsilon - f(c) = \varepsilon
$$

So, we choose $\delta = \delta_c$ from the definition of the continuity of $f$.